# How to iterate over a a predictable progression of single characters in Python?

Tags: python, range, iteration

I have a series of websites I want to look at.

The name of the each page is like this:

```
book_page = ("http://target.com/books/char/X/")
```

where X is a single letter of the alphabet.  So the range will be

```
    mylist = ['A','B','C'] etc.
```

- First, is there an expression to create that list of letters?
- And second, how do I use that directly in the FOR statement, or is that possible? e.g.

  ```
  for alpha in range(mylist):
     mypage = "http://target.com/books/char/" + alpha + "/"
  ```

When I run this I get an error because range is supposed to be an integer, but I'd rather have a text string.  I know I could do something like this (below) but I was wondering if there is another way?

Working code so far:

```
    for x in range(1, 3):
       alpha = mylist[x]
       mypage = "http://target.com/books/char/" + alpha + "/"
       print alpha, mypage
```

Comment: what's wrong with `for alpha in mylist:`

Comment: Or maybe you meant to do: `for alpha in range(len(mylist)):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sequence of letters is already in `string.ascii_uppercase`. And `for` iterates over the elements of a sequence.

```
import string

for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
   ...
```

Comment: I am such a noob I cannot even upvote answers to my own questions.  But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about a generator function of your own?

```
def charrange(start, end):
    return (chr(i) for i in xrange(ord(start), ord(end)))

for c in charrange('A', 'D'):
    print c
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

It follows the same semantics as `range`, where `end` is exclusive.  To iterate over an inclusive range:

```
def icharrange(start, end):
    return (chr(i) for i in xrange(ord(start), ord(end)+1))

for c in icharrange('A', 'D'):
    print c
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Answer (score 1):

For iterating over the values in `mylist`, there is no reason to call `range`. Instead you can simply say:

```
for alpha in mylist:
   mypage = "http://target.com/books/char/" + alpha + "/"
```

This will make `alpha` the value you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you that looks much neater!